# Corollary far away from its theorem

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

I am using `amsthm` with `thmtools`. When a corollary immediately follows its theorem, the numbering automatically outputs as

> **Theorem n**
>
> **Corollary n.1**
>
> **Proposition n+1**

But what if I insert other numbered environment in between? How do I obtain:

> **Theorem n**
>
> **Proposition n+1**
>
> **Theorem n+2**
>
> **Corollary n.1**
>
> **Proposition n+3**

Answer (score 2):

This is a modified version of @egreg's answer. It uses <...> for the label of the theorem to follow, while preserve `[...]` as description text. Thus a normal corollary still looks like

```
\begin{corollary}[description]
Another corollary
\end{corollary}
```

while a corollary numbered within a theorem labeled `\label{thm:1}` looks like

```
\begin{corollary}<thm:1>[description]
A corollary
\end{corollary}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\newtheorem{corollaryinner}{Corollary}[theorem] % just the internal version
\NewDocumentEnvironment{corollary}{D<>{}}
 {% #1 is the cross reference label
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    % we have a corollary directly following a theorem, do nothing special
  \else
    \ifcsname #1-used\endcsname
      \expandafter\xdef\csname #1-used\endcsname{\the\numexpr\csname #1-used\endcsname+1}%
    \else
      \expandafter\gdef\csname #1-used\endcsname{1}%
    \fi
    \renewcommand{\thecorollaryinner}{\ref{#1}.\csname #1-used\endcsname}%
  \fi
  \corollaryinner
 }
 {\endcorollaryinner}

\begin{document}

\section{Corollary follows directly}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}[description]
A corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}[description]
Another corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{proposition}
A proposition
\end{proposition}

\section{Corollary is detached}

\begin{theorem}\label{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
A proposition
\end{proposition}

\begin{theorem}
An unrelated theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}<theorem>[description]
A corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{proposition}
Another proposition
\end{proposition}

\begin{corollary}<theorem>[description]
Another corollary
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER:**
*You can store the value of the `theorem` counter and number the corollaries within it.*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling=theorem]{proposition}
\newcounter{theoremrecord}
\let\theoremOriginal=\theorem
\renewcommand{\theorem}{\theoremOriginal\setcounter{theoremrecord}{\value{theorem}}}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=theoremrecord]{corollary}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    ...
\end{theorem}
\begin{proposition}
    ...
\end{proposition}
\begin{corollary}
    ...
\end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, this doesn't work if I slide an unrelated theorem between the theorem and its corollary. Question edited

Comment: @giobrach I've made an edit to my answer, which is based on egreg's answer's first part, but its syntax is more natural.

Answer (score 2):

I propose to define `corollary` to take an optional argument. If empty or missing, the assumption is that the corollary refers to the last stated theorem (or proposition, of course).

If the corollary is detached, you need to add `\label` to the parent theorem and use the label as the optional argument to the corollary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\newtheorem{corollaryinner}{Corollary}[theorem] % just the internal version
\newenvironment{corollary}[1][]
 {% #1 is the cross reference label
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    % we have a corollary directly following a theorem, do nothing special
  \else
    \ifcsname #1-used\endcsname
      \expandafter\xdef\csname #1-used\endcsname{\the\numexpr\csname #1-used\endcsname+1}%
    \else
      \expandafter\gdef\csname #1-used\endcsname{1}%
    \fi
    \renewcommand{\thecorollaryinner}{\ref{#1}.\csname #1-used\endcsname}%
  \fi
  \corollaryinner
 }
 {\endcorollaryinner}

\begin{document}

\section{Corollary follows directly}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
A corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}
Another corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{proposition}
A proposition
\end{proposition}

\section{Corollary is detached}

\begin{theorem}\label{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
A proposition
\end{proposition}

\begin{corollary}[theorem]
A corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{proposition}
Another proposition
\end{proposition}

\begin{corollary}[theorem]
Another corollary
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same using `expl3` features: I maintain a property list with the cross references for the same purpose as before, to keep track of already used references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\newtheorem{corollaryinner}{Corollary}[theorem] % just the internal version

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{corollary}{o}
 {
  \IfValueT { #1 }
   {
    \giobrach_corollary_setup:n { #1 }
   }
  \corollaryinner
 }
 { \endcorollaryinner }

\prop_new:N \g_giobrach_corollary_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \giobrach_corollary_setup:n
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnx \g_giobrach_corollary_prop { #1 }
   {
    \int_eval:n { \prop_item:Nn \g_giobrach_corollary_prop { #1 } + 1 }
   }
  \cs_set:Npn \thecorollaryinner {\ref {#1}.\prop_item:Nn \g_giobrach_corollary_prop { #1 }}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Corollary follows directly}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{corollary}
A corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{corollary}
Another corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{proposition}
A proposition
\end{proposition}

\section{Corollary is detached}

\begin{theorem}\label{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
A proposition
\end{proposition}

\begin{corollary}[theorem]
A corollary
\end{corollary}

\begin{proposition}
Another proposition
\end{proposition}

\begin{corollary}[theorem]
Another corollary
\end{corollary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this play well with `cleveref`?

Comment: @giobrach It seems so. I tried and it works also with `hyperref` links. I tested only the second version, but I see no reason why the first version shouldn't work, because the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: Ok. I must admit your code looks a bit obscure to me. How would I go about controlling specifics like style, name, refname, etc.?

Comment: I suggest changing `\newenvironment{corollary}[1][]` into `\NewDocumentEnvironment{corollary}{D<>{}}`, so that `[...]` is still for corollary description, while `<...>` is for the optional counter.

Comment: @Jinwen It's possible to use two optional arguments (but the first has to be a label). I don't see much need for a nonstandard syntax.

Comment: @egreg My understanding is that, when one types `\begin{corollary}[...]`, he/she usually means to treat `...` as description, not the label. But here it will look for the label `...`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you again for your answer, but I couldn't manage to get this idea to work with `cleveref` in the way I want to. Please see the edit to my question.

Comment: @giobrach Sorry, but that's a whole new question

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the feedback. I have created a new question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586696/detached-corollaries-with-cleveref